# How to access Camera in Typescript npm?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, npm, camera

I have created an application in typescript npm with AngularJS 1. Now, I have to click photos from the camera on desktop (web-based) browser.

What is the best way to achieve the same, which will work on all browsers?

I tried many solutions but those are not supported on IE like NativeScript.

Thanks in Advance.

Thanks,
Asim Bagwan

Comment: Please share some code, What have you tried till now?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `navigator.getUserMedia`. You can best Google that.

If you want a readily available solution, consider checking out the browser implementation of the Cordova camera plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/src/browser/CameraProxy.js